# Python selenium doesn't click on on the cookie accept button

Tags: python, selenium, cookies, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I want to access a website but I just can't get the cookie pop up to go away. The website itself opens but I can't seem to grab the accept button for the cookie. Here is my code thus far:

```
#set path, open firefox
path = r'C:\Users\Anwender\Downloads\geckodriver-v0.30.0-win64\geckodriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=path)

#open bym forum
driver.get('https://www.bym.de/forum/')

#deal with the effing cookie message
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,15)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/button[2]/span'))).click()

#log in
username = driver.find_element_by_id("navbar_username")
password = driver.find_element_by_id("navbar_password")
username.send_keys("my_username")
password.send_keys("my_password")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/main/div[3]/div[1]/ul/li[2]/form/fieldset/div/div/input[4]").click()
```

The log in code I included to mention that I have used the exact same syntax to log into a different website so I am not sure how to get past this. The html code of the cookie button "accept" (here: "Zustimmung") is:

```html
<button title="Zustimmen" class="message-component message-button no-children focusable button global-font-headline sp_choice_type_11 last-focusable-el" style="padding: 14px 40px 12px; margin: 12px 0px; border-width: 1px; border-color: rgb(102, 102, 102); border-radius: 20px; border-style: solid; font-size: 12px; font-weight: 700; color: rgb(17, 17, 17); font-family: georgia, serif; width: calc(100% - 80px); background: rgb(255, 255, 255) none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">Zustimmen</button>
```

I have tried to grab the button by css path or by name as well but I just have no idea why it doesn't work. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accept button is present inside an `iframe` and you need to switch `iframe` first in order to access the element.

Use webdriverwait() and wait for frame to be available and switch.

//switch to iframe

```
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[title='SP Consent Message']")))
```

//click on accept button

```
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"button[title='Zustimmen']"))).click()
```

You need to import below libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Comment: Thanks so much, that did the trick! May I ask if I could have seen the problem? Did you just know it could be the problem or is there some kind of wording that gives it away? In the html for example? Also thanks to @DebanjanB

Comment: Ah, nevermind, I found the iframe!

Answer (score 1):

The element <kbd>ZUSTIMMEN</kbd> is within an [`<iframe>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe) so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603847/how-to-sleep-webdriver-in-python-for-milliseconds/52607451#52607451) for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

    ```
    driver.get("https://www.bym.de/forum/")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[title='SP Consent Message']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[title='Zustimmen']"))).click()
    ```
  - Using `XPATH`:

    ```
    driver.get("https://www.bym.de/forum/")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@title='SP Consent Message']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@title='Zustimmen']"))).click()
    ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
   from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
   from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
   from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)
- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)